# How to paste images into PowerPoint

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I have an image copied into the clipboard and would like to past this image into a slide using Microsoft powershell.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mathias.

Comment: You should comment on his answer, and not your own question. Anyways, if his answer solved your problem, kindly tick the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`PasteSpecial` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745158.aspx).

Here is an example using a new blank presentation, pasting whatever is in the clipboard to a new slide:

```
# Open PowerPoint
$PowerPoint = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application

# Create a new presentation
$Presentation = $PowerPoint.Presentations.Add($false)

# Create a new title slide
$Slide = $Presentation.Slides.Add(1,11)

# Paste contents of clipboard to slide
$Pasted = $Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(0,$false,$null,$null,$null,$null)
```

`$Pasted` will contain a range reference to the image you just pasted

Comment: Thank you Mathias. This is very helpful. It does past an image if the clipboard image was from the mouse. When I do CopyToClipboard calling another application from powershell however there is no image there.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question (probably related to the range/selection expression you use). Feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and remember to include a code sample of how you're currently attempting it